# Webserver on 512MB Ram on VPS?

Tags: 14.04, apache2, nginx, vps, lighttpd

Would you advise using Apache on a 512m RAM on VPS, my understanding is  that it consumes a lot of memory compared to NGINX and LIGHTTPD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends of what you like to run on the web server - complex php site with hundreds consumers for example.

I have a VPS with Ubuntu 16.04 and Apache2 and in its initial state, it consumes under 100 MB RAM when it is idle. But with couple of additional modules, SQL server, Wikimedia site, etc. it consumes about 400 MB RAM on idle state.